# why does (sender,e) => SomeAction() works on winforms and not in asp.net

Tags: .net-4.0, delegates, lambda

I have the following code:

```
btnTest.Click += (sender,e) => SomeAction()
```

why does this code works in WinForms and not in asp.net. In asp.net I had to do the following:

```
btnTest.Click += new EventHandler(SomeAction);
```

target framework in both cases is .net 4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible you are trying to call

```
btnTest.Click += (sender,e) => SomeAction()
```

from inside the Page_Load method or another event handler?  In that case the parameters "sender" and "e" are already declared and can be causing a conflict.

Change the definition to:

```
btnTest.Click += (s,ea) => SomeAction();
```

You'll probably want to forward the arguments to your function though:

```
btnTest.Click += (s,ea) => SomeAction(s, ea);
```

Comment: Your Page_Load already defines sender and e, so you can't use those as parameters in your event delegate declaration.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine is ASP.NET 4.0 for me:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
   }

   private void SomeFunc()
   {
      Button1.Click += (sender, e) => SomeAction();
   }

   private void SomeAction()
   {
   }
}
```