# Create an event handler without a method

Tags: c#, events, buttonclick

I need to create an event handler that would be local to a method. Can I do anything like that?

```
ddd.btnSave.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(
                void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
                {

                }
            );
```

Comment: Search: `C# event tutorial`

Comment: no..... you can't do [works someaction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4017666/why-does-sender-e-someaction-works-on-winforms-and-not-in-asp-net) like that :D

Comment: [Events Tutorial MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: user1834420 : you are funny!

Answer (score 2):

```
ddd.btnSave.Click += (sender, e) => {
    //handle event
};
```

alternatively using the `delegate` syntax:

```
ddd.btnSave.Click += delegate(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
   //handle event
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a lambda expression:

```
ddd.btnSave.Click += (sender, e) => {
  ...
};
```